# Program to open .fig files saved by Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

Is there any program able to open .fig files saved by Matlab?

Comment: You mean, besides Matlab itself? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 29/04/2016**

According to [johnml1135's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36923358/2140414), fig files are essentially just mat files, and johnml1135 figured out where the various plot elements are stored, for converting a fig file to a Python plot.

**Original**

According to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269195/saving-fig-file-from-octave) the fig file saved by Matlab is in a proprietary binary format. I don't know of any other software capable of loading this format.

Your best option is probably to have the figure saved as a pdf/png from within Matlab depending on the type of figure.

**Possible workaround**

I recently noticed that `octave` will load a fig file as a structure, so if you're stuck with trying to open fig files without being able to access Matlab you could try and write an octave function that will load the fig file and reconstitute the plot from the contents of the `struct`. This would probably require knowing prior information about the plot though.

Comment: Actually, Python/SciPy can read the files as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36923358/2140414).

Comment: @johnml1135 : Thanks for the link to your solution - it seems then that fig files are just mat files and you've figured out the structures that the various plot items correspond to - nice!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @mutzmatron, `.fig` is not easily opened, but this is mostly due to it being poorly documented (not sure about proprietary aspects...). As can be seen [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/), there is a simple format to them quite similar to `.mat` files, which might give you another direction to go in.

I've always been quite fond of [plot2svg](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401). It exports Matlab figures (most anyway) to the non-proprietary vector format SVG.

Comment: I tried `plot2svg` once and found it a bit buggy - but I was mostly wondering what the pros and cons are to svg over pdf?

Comment: Yes, it's buggy, and Mathworks should start supporting it natively! Pros and cons are too numerous -- it deserves its own post. Most relevant for me has always been that SVG is supported by most browsers natively, whereas PDF support has always been difficult. Also, image conversion from PDF to something else can be a pain, whereas SVG has never treated me badly.

Answer (score 3):

Create a script (for example FigViewer.m) containing simply the command `figure` and compile it by running

> mcc -e -v FigViewer.m

from the Matlab command window. This way you get a platform-dependent application that runs on any computer with the right version of the [Matlab Compiler Runtime](http://www.mathworks.de/products/compiler/mcr/) installed, which is freely available. If you are looking for further information on the Matlab Compiler, use the MathWorks homepage instead of Google since some information is available only behind a login screen and thus cannot be found by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Python through SciPy has the ability to open a fig file (scipy.io.loadmat), which is really just a mat file by another name.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36923358/2140414) can show simple line plots with labels, etc. but can easily be extended.  It is fairly straightforward to grab the data from it as well.

Answer (score -2):

As it turns out, there is actually a command in matlab itself that lets you save any figures you want to file in whatever format. Try this:

```
print('theNameYouWant','-dpng')
```

This lets you save the figure to a png file which can then be opened by numerous applications like MS Paint or Paintbrush on Mac