# Unable to open .fig file

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, backwards-compatibility, mat-file

I am using MATLAB 6.5 release and after downloading some free online MATLAB source code - I am unable to open .fig files. .m files open up perfectly and execute properly. I am using MATLAB 6.5 version.

Screen attached.[image: .fig file open error]

I am assuming that these .fig files may have been created by later versions of MATLAB software. So how can I open them in prior release namely 6.5 version.

Comment: Can you open .fig files which you save by your own matlab version?

Comment: yes, I can open .fig files saved by my own MATLAB version

Comment: Off the top of my head: there is indeed a break of backwards compatibility somewhere around V7.0. The only way to open .fig files generated on later versions in V6.5 is to save them with compatibility flags switched on...Of course, you need a newer MATLAB version to do that.

Comment: Happy do to that or you; just upload the file somewhere and I'll do the conversion

Comment: Thanks, but that would be only one such file now - but a lot while studying online, is there a generic way I can open them

Comment: @Prakash: Well, I have little experience with this, but [supposedly you can load .fig files in Octave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902650/program-to-open-fig-files-saved-by-matlab), and then convert them to some other format MATLAB V6.5 understands (EPS, JPG, etc.).

Comment: try using "load filename.fig". I read in documentation fig files are mat files. the variable should be figure handles